# Перезаливка файлов на Git

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

Разбираюсь как работать с Git и сегодня столкнулся с такой проблемой. Когда создавал проект то все классы писал с маленькой буквы:

```
public class loginTest {}
```

Далее я переименовал все классы c большой буквы:

```
public class LoginTest {}
```

Но на гит все равно заливались файлы со старым именем loginTest.
Как полностью обновить все файлы проекта? 
Работаю в Idea, на гит заливаю через нее.

Comment: `на гит заливаю` – гит это вообще программа, а вы явно имели в виду удаленный репозиторий. Так вот, сначала все изменения попадают в ваш локальный репозиторий — по командам `git add` и `git commit`. Потом уже вы отправляете их в удаленный, например на гитхаб.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте в Idea вкладку Terminal, далее:

```
git add .
git commit -m "fix"
git push
```

попробуйте посмотреть файлы помечены как изменённые:

```
git status
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: А `git-status` вы точно с дефисом имели в виду?

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает. Что означает "-a" в команде git commit -a -m "fix" ??

Comment: Все описания команд доступны [здесь](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)

Comment: После `git add .` параметр `-a` в `git commit` не имеет смысла. Программы `git-status` нет — это скорее всего опечатка, в крайнем случае псевдоним.

Comment: спасибо что поправили